# Unable to Run Ionic Cordova Android Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been trying to run my ionic app in the android emulator and am getting continuous errors around some sort of versioning.  Below is the error I am getting when I run `sudo ionic cordova emulate android`

```
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
/Users/DrewGelinas/Desktop/lndFinal/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/customtabsclient/shared/CustomTabsHelper.java:77: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6

        List<String> packagesSupportingCustomTabs = new ArrayList<>();

                                                                  ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
/Users/DrewGelinas/Desktop/lndFinal/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/customtabsclient/shared/ServiceConnection.java:32: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6

        mConnectionCallback = new WeakReference<>(connectionCallback);
                                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
2 errors

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac 
FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I have checked android studio and the most recent android SDK and the sdk tools are all installed.  I have also checked the JAVA_HOME variable and it is set to the proper place running java 1.8.  I can't figure out what this issue is, or what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the [Safari View Controller](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/safari-view-controller/) native plugin solved it for me. Try either updating it or removing it. I use the [In App Browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) and it works great. Project in question uses `ionic-angular` `3.8.0` and Angular `4.4.4`.

Comment: Solved this issue, still getting an `Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot find module 'android-versions'` error, but that seems like it may just be the ANDROID_HOME variable causing issues

Answer (score 0):

As with Alex Steinberg, removing the Safari View Controller worked for me as well on an ionic build.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me, you may need to keep the Safari View Controller plugin.  Removing wasn't an option.  Upgrading from 1.4.7 to 1.5.3 got rid of this error for me.